# Call ThreadPoolExecutor.execute but not really executed

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

I'm using Java's ThreadPoolExecutor in my project.

The constructor method is as below:

```
threadBlockingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue(100);

threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(2, 4, 100, TimeUnit.SECONDS, threadBlockingQueue, new RejectedExecutionHandler() {

    @Override
    public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
        LOGGER.error("Thread Pool Reject Job");
    }
});
```

I call ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(Runnable), but finally some of the tasks has not been executed at all. Most of the tasks could be executed, but still a few disappeared without any exception in the log. And I also did not find any log in RejectedExecutionHandler which I passed as a parameter of ThreadPoolExecutor's contructor method.

Failed to find any clue for this issue. Is there any one who encountered this issue before?

Thanks.

Comment: how many jobs does your code attempts to execute? keep in mind, the max pool size is 4, if you have more threads, then the rest will be in the queue waiting for the other threads to complete.

Comment: I hope the task that you attempted to execute are of Runnable.

Comment: Thansk for your reply. First, all the item that I want to execute are runnable. Second, the qps is quite small, based on the log, most of the time the queue size is less than 10. Even if there are a lot of task in the queue, the task will still be executed sooner or later.

Comment: Agree, the queued tasks will be executed sooner or later but if some of the running threads are waiting for I/O or hung for some reason and the pool is exhausted, the queued tasks will never be executed or rejected. Kindly share the code for the tasks which you attempted to execute - that may reveal something.

Answer (score 0):

RejectedExecutionHandler is called when quueue is full, you can implement your own and pass it to TheadPoolExecutor constructor.

The following one add the Runnable into the queue once space becomes available.

The following implementation will execute all tasks:

```
new RejectedExecutionHandler {
    public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
    try {
        executor.getQueue().put(r); // waiting if necessary for space to become available
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        throw new RejectedExecutionException(ex);
    }
}
```

Another way to not loose tasks is to use the right Policy as RejectedExecutionHandler:

> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy

will runs the rejected task directly in the calling thread of the execute method.

> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor#execute